# CodeIgniter 3 : Rewriting URL with assets

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, routes, codeigniter-3

I'm facing a problem with URL rewriting in CodeIgniter 3.

My files structure is :

```
site
    -assets (.css and .js files)
    -application (sites files : controller, ...)
    -system (CI files)
    -user_guide
```

To avoid index.php/ in URL, I put this configuration :

> .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|resources|robots.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

> config.php

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

This way, my URL is not *test.com/index.php/user/function* but ***test.com/user/function***.
Actually **everything is working very well**, but when some .js scripts try to call other scripts with relative URL, it calls wrong URLs. 
For example, if one of my script wants to call `assets/js/jsfile.js`, I'm having a 404 error because it calls `http://www.test.com/user/assets/js/jsfile.js`, whereas it should be `http://www.test.com/assets/js/jsfile.js`.

To avoid this, I put `<?php echo base_url() ?>` in every `<link>` or `<script>` I call myself, but some .js libraries require intern callings, and I can not do this every time... I would like the real solution... Any idea ? Thanks a lot !

Comment: have you set ur base_url in config.php as well

Comment: Yes I have ! And it works well since in my <script> tag I use it easily. The problem is when scripts use uri like "assets/..." ...

Comment: Since you mention `<script>' tags, I assume you have inline JavaScript in some view files. Is that right? Are those the ones having trouble with relative URLs?

Comment: Hello ! Yes I have ! They were having problem with relative uri like ‘assets/js/..’ that we’re transformed in “http://www.test.com/user/assets...” so calling my controller class ! I had to put “href=‘<?php echo base_url().’assets/js/...’”?>to make it works properly! But there is still a problem with some libraries calling with relatives uro, and my configuration is redirecting to my class controller systematically...

Answer (score 0):

Change your htaccess file like this;

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|resources|robots.txt|assets)
```

Comment: Thanks ! I tried your solution but it is not solving my problem ... :'(

Comment: Hi John, try this: "RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt|assets)"